# Not to pool more than X mails on queue

Tags: postfix, email-server, email

I am doing web hosting and my biggest problem is mass mailer clients. I made lot research about this but I don't know do I ask wrong question.

We are setting a send limit but it cannot be a solution because server goes on queuing and fails after a while.

Isn't there a solution to set a **queue limit not send limit** per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation and this helped me a lot: [postfwd](http://postfwd.org/)

It can be used like a normal Postfix policy service and it allows you to create a lot of complex rules. Probably you are going to be able to satisfy your requirement using the rate limits: [ratelimit example](http://postfwd.org/ratelimits.html)

Using the postfwd your server will not keep queueing the emails until it dies, once the policy daemon returns a bad value to Postfix, Postfix can simply reject the mail before it's submitted because the policy checking can happen early in the submission process. For example if you use the policy service like in this example, then it's already checked when the client does the `mail from:`, so before the queueing: [Quick start guide, step 5](http://postfwd.org/quick.html#step5)

Comment: Oh it looks this is what I looking for. Thanks Mauro, I will check it if is really what I need.